# What format does the git documentation use to describe commands?

Tags: git, command-line, documentation

Is there a documented format that this git [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) is using? I.e. what is the importance of keywords enclosed in <>, or []. What is the difference between '-' and '--' when used before keywords?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+does+brackets+mean+documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[this]` is optional.

`<that>` is a placeholder text for something. For example, `<refspec>` could be replaced with `HEAD`, or `my_branch`.

`--` is announcing a full name option, where `-` introduces the short form, but it's only a difference in syntax. Example for cherry-pick command : `--no-commit` and `-n` (they will do the same thing)

Comment: so any <that> must be provided or the command will not work?

Comment: @JohnOsborne if it's not otherwise marked as optional, like in `[<this>]`, yes you must provide it.